# How do I add numbers to “h2 tags”

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordrpess site. I want add numbers to "h2 tags"

I want to do it via php(functions.php)

The format of my posts:

```
text

<h2>text</h2>

text

<h2>text</h2>

text

<h2>text</h2>
...
...
```

I want this:

```
text

<h2>NUMBER-1 text</h2>

text

<h2>NUMBER-2 text</h2>

text

<h2>NUMBER-3 text</h2>
...
...
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? You getting any errors?

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13083/display-post-number-not-post-id-number](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13083/display-post-number-not-post-id-number) (can't flag cause it's another stackexange)

Answer (score -1):

You can use ordered list with style attribute:

```
<ol type="N" style="font-weight: bold;font-size:20px">
  <li><span style="font-weight: normal;font-size:10px">text</span></li>    
  <li><span style="font-weight: normal;font-size:10px">text</span></li>    
  <li><span style="font-weight: normal;font-size:10px">text</span></li>    
</ol>
```

Simplified with css:
    
    ol {font-weight: bold;font-size:20px;}
    span {font-weight: normal;font-size:10px;}

```
<ol type="N">    
  <li><span>text</span></li>    
  <li><span>text</span></li>    
  <li><span>text</span></li>    
</ol>
```